# Rigth click event for asp.net listview item

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview

I have a listview and I need to add a popup opens for right click event. Currently I have implemented it with jquery. But initial load of the page, right click is not working. But if I refresh the page, then right click is working. I have look into html source and I can see all the markup and jquery variables loaded correctly.

This is my markup.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvKeywords" OnItemDataBound="lvKeywords_ItemDataBound" OnItemDeleting="lvKeywords_ItemDeleting" 
            DataKeyNames="Key" runat="server" OnItemUpdating="lvKeywords_OnItemUpdating" >
  <ItemTemplate>

      <div id="<%#Eval("Key") %>" class="fsKeywordItem">
          <asp:Literal ID="ltrlKeyword" runat="server"></asp:Literal>                 
      </div>

      <%--this is the popup--%>
      <div class="smartPopUp" id="<%#Eval("Suggession") %>" style="display: none;">
          <%-- there are some html controls here --%>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#" + '<%#Eval("Key") %>').mousedown(function (event) {
                    switch (event.which) {
                           case 3:
                                 event.preventDefault();
                                 showPopup('<%#Eval("Suggession") %>');
                           }
               });

               $("#" + '<%#Eval("Key") %>').bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
               });
            });
      </script>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function showPopup(divId) {
      $("#" + divId).css("display", "block");
   }
</script>
```

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Check it 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63902/Right-Click-Menu-using-JQuery-ASP-NET-using-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is happen because of document.ready(). So remove that jquery part inside the Listview and use javascript to accomplish it.

So, I'll give you a example for your listview.

```
  oncontextmenu='showPopup("popupDivId"); return false;'
```

add this to your div as below

```
  <div id="<%#Eval("Key") %>" class="fsKeywordItem" oncontextmenu='showPopup("popupDivId"); return false;'>
      <asp:Literal ID="ltrlKeyword" runat="server"></asp:Literal>                 
  </div>

  <%--this is the popup--%>
  <div class="smartPopUp" id="<%#Eval("Suggession") %>" style="display: none;">
      <%-- there are some html controls here --%>
  </div>
```

What will happen here is, oncontextmenu will fire rigth click event and then we call our function there. then "return false" will stop default behaviour of right click event. That means it will stop default right click menu of the browser.

Hope you can find a solution by using oncontextmenu.

:)